# Strange behavior when using Row with packed arrays

Tags: bugs, formatting

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Today I lost a lot of time with a strange behavior and I narrowed it down to this small piece of code:

```
a = {1, 2};
ToString@Row[DeleteDuplicates[a], ","]
ToString@Row[Union[a], ","]
```

> ```
> "Row[{1, 2}, ,]"
> "1,2"
> ```

Can someone explain this bizarre behavior? Is this a bug?

This is interesting too:

```
a = {1, 2};
l1 = DeleteDuplicates[a];
l2 = Union[a];
l1==l2
s1 = ToString@Row[l1, ","]
s2 = ToString@Row[l2, ","]
s1==s2
```

> ```
> True
> "Row[{1, 2}, ,]"
> "1,2"
> False
> ```

There is some "memory" in `l1` created using `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: Interesting. If you `Apply` `List` to the `DeleteDuplicates`, results are peachy.

Comment: Confirmed in 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 on OS X.  Very weird and slightly disturbing.  I guess you should report it to support.

Comment: @Murta: Might want to change title to `Row` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`... a bit less alarming ;-)

Comment: @rasher done! But `Row` to me is alarming to :). I use it to inject information into some SQL strings, and now I have to Unpack it using FromPackedArray (very annoying).

Comment: please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when asking a question... if users (or WRI support/devs) confirm in the comments that it is indeed a weird behaviour/bug, then it can be retagged as such.

Comment: @rm-rf It was confirmed by Wolfram Support. We can tag it.

Comment: @Murta Thanks. I did not remove the tag when I edited, because there was already some discussion in the comments by then. I meant it more for future reference :) The main reason we have this rule is because sometimes a certain behaviour might appear to be a bug, but it actually might be documented or expected (but unknown to the user).

Comment: Appears to have been fixed in V10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually this happens when `Row` contains a packed array.  `DeleteDuplicates` packs the array.  `Union` doesn't.  A simpler way to replicate the behaviour:

```
ToString@Row[Developer`ToPackedArray[{1,2}], ","]

(* ==> "Row[{1, 2}, ,]" *)
```

The default form used by `ToString` is `OutputForm` and the following also exhibits the problem:

```
OutputForm[Row[Developer`ToPackedArray[{1, 2}], ","]]

(* ==> Row[{1, 2}, ,] *)
```

I can reproduce it in both 8.0.4 and 9.0.1.  I'd say it's a bug and you should report it to support.

Comment: Tks @Szabolcs, just reported (CASE:628688). Reproduced in V10 beta too. Let's see if final version 10 solves that.

Comment: Quick-draw analysis! +1

Answer (score 5):

As Szabolcs notes this occurs only when the first argument of `Row` is a packed array.  In this case `DeleteDuplicates` returns a packed array while `Union` does not, which explains that difference:

```
<< Developer`
a = {1, 2};
b = Union @ a;
c = DeleteDuplicates @ a;
PackedArrayQ /@ {b, c}
```

> ```
> {False, True}
> ```

One can see that this is not an issue of `Row` itself as these render as expected:

```
Row[b, ","]
Row[c, ","]
```

> ```
> 1, 2
> 1, 2
> ```

Rather, The variance occurs in `OutputForm`, which is normally not used in the Notebook interface, but which is the format that `ToString` defaults to:

```
Row[b, ","] // OutputForm
Row[c, ","] // OutputForm
```

> ```
> 1,2
>
> Row[{1, 2}, ,]
> ```

I suspect that since `Row` was introduced in version 6, and it is ostensibly a 2D formatting function (it is not merely a string concatenation utility), someone forgot to update OutputForm to work in this edge case.  For the case at hand one can easily avoid the problem by specifying the default Notebook format, `StandardForm`:

```
ToString[Row[b, ","], StandardForm]
ToString[Row[c, ","], StandardForm]
```

> ```
> "1, 2"
> "1, 2"
> ```

Comment: Much better use `StandardForm` instead of `FromPackedArray` as I was doing. Tks

Comment: Change my mind.. Now using `StringJoin@Riffle[ToString /@ a, ","]`