# Opposite of StringSplit

Tags: string-manipulation

What is an appropriate command that does the opposite of the following?

```
StringSplit["a b c d e f g"," "]
```

Comment: Yes, shot before aiming ;-) - deleted comment... but it still is broken, e.g. with leading spaces...

Comment: `res = StringSplit[s = " a b c d e  f   g ", " "];
StringJoin@Riffle[res, " "];
% == s` will be False... fails with trailing spaces also. Don't think one can correctly reconstruct all stings from a string split...

Comment: Of course, but then that's not reconstructing the original string `s`, is it... bottom line, there is no direct inverse for the title form for all strings.

Comment: Not sure there is one that fits your needs. Adding `All` as the optional third argument to the split allows correct reconstruction of all strings, but then you will have the "excess" (any leading/trailing/adjacent whitespace) as members of the split.

Comment: Related: [(7063)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7063/121),
[(20412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A combination of `StringJoin` and `Riffle`:

```
res = StringSplit["a b c d e f g"," "];
StringJoin@Riffle[res," "]
```

Comment: you beat me by 10 seconds! I'll delete my answer...

Comment: @bills yep, that was a close one!

Comment: @WRI, why not just StringJoin[res," "]

Comment: ...& operator form StringJoin["/"] eg list of strings --> path

Comment: @alancalvitti Turns out WRI has fixed this in 10.1, see Murta's answer.

Comment: this fails to do the inverse.  For example it doesn't match the output of the following js `" a b ".split(" ").join(" ")`

Comment: @William  `StringSplit[" a b c "," "]` is just `{"a", "b", "c"}` so information is lost. There is no way you could know if there were a leading or ending space in the original string. This is the closest to an inverse that you can come. In Javascript that information is preserved by `split`.

Comment: @William ...if you want it to work like your Javascript example you can use `StringSplit[" a b c ", " ", All]`.

Answer (score 12):

In version 10.1 you can use [`StringRiffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
res = StringSplit["a b c d e f g", " "];
StringRiffle[res]
```

Use no second argument for spaces, or something else for something else. A nice advantage of `StringRiffle` is that `res` elements can be non string elements, and it will be automatically converted. It's something I miss in `StringJoin`.

PS: this answer is based on Docs, I don't have V10.1.

Take care with `ToString@Row` in V9 or older. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41653), about some problems.

Comment: This fails for example it doesn't match the following js `" a b ".split(" ").join(" ")`
"

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can you this alternative:

```
res = StringSplit["a b c d e f g", " "];

ToString @ Row[res, " "]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, I know, Kuba's and Pickett's solutions are preferable. 
For those who fancy Patterns here is an alternative.

```
   StringReplace[res, t : __ :> t <> " "] // StringJoin  // #~StringDrop~ -1 &
```

Doesn't look elegant, anyhow.....it works...hi,hi,hi.!

Answer (score 1):

```
res = StringSplit["a b c d e f g", " "];    
Fold[#1 <> " " <> #2 &, res]
(*"a b c d e f g"*)
```